# How is the mechanism of releasing TCP port in HTTPClientFactory?

Tags: asp.net-core, httpclient, tcpclient, httpclientfactory

In my current version of a project, the **HttpClinet** has been used for creating requests. But in request's peak time most of our TCP ports get in **waited status**, Their status remains about 2 minutes event after task completion. I read some articles about **IHttpClientFactory**.

But I'm not sure how this solution can solve our problems. Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the exact status? TIME_WAIT? That is purely a matter of OS-settings, the application has already closed the connection but the TCP-stack keeps the port open to catch late packages.

Comment: The excat status is CLOSE_WAIT

Comment: And some other times has Time_wait status

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are tonnes of articles out there which would tell you why you should not dispose HttpClient (which would result in what you mentioned, and end-up with socket exhaustion issue), but rather to use IHttpClientFactory to manage the life-cycle of of HttpClient-related services.

This is because each time you make a request with HttpClient, and dispose it after usage, would cause the socket to be in a TIME_WAIT state, and imagine if you make few thousands of requests in few seconds, you will run out of sockets. The IHttpClientFactory is a contract to better manage your Http services, and to re-use sockets from the connection pool without you having to manage it.

As a start, go through this, I think it provides sufficient info. about what you want to achieve,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests

One of the key point in the article above, to answer your question about how IHttpClientFactory can solve your issue,

> Each time you get an HttpClient object from the IHttpClientFactory, a
>   new instance is returned. But each HttpClient uses an
>   HttpMessageHandler that's pooled and reused by the IHttpClientFactory
>   to reduce resource consumption, as long as the HttpMessageHandler's
>   lifetime hasn't expired.

Hope this helps!